# How to execute the corresponding function according to the string variable?

Tags: python

As the title, I need to execute the corresponding function according to the different values of the string variable,

`Choice_function` is a function that needs to be optimized. If I have a lot of functions that need to be executed, using `if else` is more cumbersome. Is there any easy way to optimize the `choice_function` function?

My code is as follows:

```
def function1():
    print('function1')
    return


def function2():
    print('function2')
    return


def choice_function(name):
    if name == 'function1':
        function1()
    elif name == 'function2':
        function2()
    return


def main():
    function_name = 'function1'
    choice_function(function_name)
    function_name = 'function2'
    choice_function(function_name)
    return


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Consider using a dictionary where the keys are function_name and corresponding values refer to the appropriate function. Call your dictionary **D** then **D['functions1']()** Of course this will fail miserably if the key doesn't exist. You should account for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You can use `vars` to do it

#### code:

```
def function1():
    print('function1')
    return


def function2():
    print('function2')
    return

vars()["function1"]()
vars()["function2"]()
```

#### result:

```
function1
function2
```

- if you want to use it in a function like `choice_function`, you can use `globals`.

```
def function1():
    print('function1')
    return


def function2():
    print('function2')
    return

def choice_function(name):
    try:
        globals()[name]()
    except Exception:
        print(f"no found function: {name}")
    return

def main():
    function_name = 'function1'
    choice_function(function_name)
    function_name = 'function2'
    choice_function(function_name)
    return

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Sole `vars()` merely produces `globals()` and should be replaced with such.